# Cant access MYSQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

Ive been having this issue for weeks now. Currently we have an app that has to use a Mysql database hosted by Godaddy to access certain info, and php files on our in house server to access info from a legacy system (as we migrate slowly)

We want to put the MySql database onto the in house server so that we have no need to use godaddy anymore, and its much more manageable.

I have installed MySql and MySql workbench, i have confirmed that the service is running in the services on the server, i can get into localhost on workbench and create a table (see below)

[image: running localhost]

And i can run querys locally etc.

The problem is when i try to query the database via php externally its not working and i have tried everything, ive even disabled the whole firewalls on the server and opened up port 3306. This is my php :

```
<?PHP   
$user_name = "root";  
$password = "dont be nosey";  
$database = "tst";  
$server = "myserveripaddress";  
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);  
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);  
if($db_handle)    
{         
    print "Connected";  
}  
else  
{  
    print "Can not connect to server";  
}         
if ($db_found)   
{ 
     print "DataBase found";  
}  
else   
{  
    print "DataBase not found";  
}  
?>
```

and all i get is :

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on XXXXX (4) in /home/hiltonsmythe/public_html/gdad/testing.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/hiltonsmythe/public_html/gdad/testing.php on line 7
Can not connect to serverDataBase not found
```

Ive tried multiple users and yes they have % wildcard permissions. Any ideas? Also its worth mentioning i do have iis running on this server with php installed and i do query the database via that, so its not like the server is blocking - seems to be a mysql issue?

Comment: have you tried using either the MySQLi_ or PDO API? what's the version of PHP?

Comment: Have you tried logging in interactively from the machine you are running PHP on to the db?  I have a feeling it might have something to do with the password.

Comment: Are you sure that your GoDaddy server allows remote connections?

Comment: Could it because iis is on localhost?

Comment: godaddy is fine thats not the problem, i have installed mysql on my new server i want to migrate FROM godaddy

Comment: Probably your mysql server is refusing remote connection. Google on how to allow them on your server.

Comment: I have done but nothing is working

Answer (score 1):

As shown in your nice picture, MySQL only listens to localhost connections.

You should adjust the `bind-address` (or comment it out) in your `my.cnf` (usually in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) configuration file and restart `mysqld`.

Comment: What should i adjust it too? and thanks, i am proud of my picture :D

Comment: @G.Smith To your server IP obviously, http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/remotemysql.htm

Comment: Look for `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and correct the `bind-address` to include your real IP address or to comment it out to allow connections from all IPs.

Comment: this is on windows server

Comment: On Windows, the configuration file should normally be in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini`.